# The patent for dog leashes

Tags: ca2742535a1

In reference to the patent: [CA2742535A1](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2742535A1)

I'd like to know if the dog leash in Amazon ([http://www.amazon.com/Explore-Retractable-26-Feet-Supports-110-Pound/dp/B005NK5DEU/ref=sr_1_1?s=pet-supplies&ie=UTF8&qid=1436285688&sr=1-1&keywords=Retractable+Dog+Leash](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005NK5DEU)) is referring to this patent when they say "The patented one-hand braking and recoil system" in their leash, as this only mentions weapons.

Answer (score 1):

No. As the **A** at the end of the patent number shows, this is a patent application, not a granted patent. If they say *patented,* they are referring to a granted patent, else it would be *patent pending*.

Answer (score 0):

There are several U.S. patents relating to animal leashes with original assignee "Flexi-Bogdahn Technik Gmbh & Co. Kg"; I think most likely they are referring to one of these patents.